# Compute $\iint (x+y)\,dx\, dy$ with circle constraint $x^{2}+y^{2}=x+y$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

I have a double integral:

$$\iint (x+y)\,dx\, dy$$

with circle constraint:
$$x^{2}+y^{2}=x+y$$

I tried to calculate it with transition to polar coordinates:

$$x^{2}+y^{2}=x+y$$
$$\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}+\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

In polar coordinates:

$$r^{2}(\cos(\varphi))^{2} + r^{2}(\sin(\varphi))^{2} = r\cos(\varphi) + r\sin(\varphi)$$
$$r = \cos(\varphi) + \sin(\varphi)$$

Graph looks like this:

[image]

But i don't understand how to find polar radius change interval here. If i separate circle into two, for first half circle for example it will go from $\textbf{some point}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. I don't understand how to find that $\textbf{some point}$, cause it starts from point ($\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = -0.2071$).

Comment: Consider changing coordinates as $x=1+r\cos\varphi$, $y=1+r\sin\varphi$.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, a double integral is done with respect to the 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure, but your domain of integration is 1-dimensional. So unless you're happy with the answer '0', you probably mean a line integral rather than a double integral.

Comment: @TomSharpe Or maybe the integral over the disk whose boundary is the circle?

Comment: Well, then one would expect the OP to have said something like "$x^2+y^2\leq x+y$".

Comment: @manabou11 You should probably either accept an answer, or provide more details as to what your looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are asked to evaluate the integral, $I$, of the function $f(x,y)=x+y$ over the disk defined by the boundary circle $x^2+y^2= x+y$.  We can express $I$ in Cartesian coordinates as

$$I=\int_{1/2-1/\sqrt2}^{1/2+1/\sqrt2} \int_{1/2-\sqrt{1/2-(y-1/2)^2}}^{1/2+\sqrt{1/2-(y-1/2)^2}} (x+y)\,dx\,dy$$

If we make a brute force transformation to polar coordinates, $(r,\phi)$, then the locus of points on the boundary of the disk are given by $r=\cos(\phi)+\sin(\phi)$ with $\phi\in [-\pi/4,3\pi/4]$ serving as a parameter.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_{-\pi/4}^{3\pi/4} \int_0^{\cos(\phi)+\sin(\phi)}(r\cos(\phi)+r\sin(\phi))\,r\,dr\,d\phi\\\\
\end{align}$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: thanks, and how did you get $\frac{3\pi}{4} and \frac{-\pi}{4}$ from $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: could you write the transformation more detailed please?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Note that $r=0$ when $\sin(\phi)+\cos(\phi)=0$.  The values for $\phi$ that satisfy this equation are $-\pi/4+n\pi$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.  If we restrict $\phi$ to be between $-\pi$ and $\pi$, then $\phi=-\pi/4$ and $\phi=3\pi/4$ are the permitted solutions.

Comment: i didn't really got this part that only values for $\varphi$ that satisfy $sin(\varphi)+cos(\varphi)$ are $\frac{-\pi}{4}+n\pi$

Comment: Let me try this.  $$r=\sin(\phi)+\cos(\phi)=0\implies \tan(\phi)=-1\implies \phi =-\pi/4+n\pi$$for any integer $n$ since the tangent function is $\pi$-periodic.  Is that clearer?

Comment: The downvoter has been annichilator :-)

Comment: @sebastiano Thank you!  Much appreciated.

Comment: @MarkViola ahahahah. Thank you to you from Sicily. I not like the "hater". I am happy when the user are happy. Sometimes can, please, see my recent and old questions? I'm happy to have also a your point of view.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 possible answers I can see, depending on what you meant.

1: What you said—a 2D integral over a 1D set. In this case the answer is 0, no working required.

2: A line integral over the curve $C:x^2+y^2=x+y$. We can parametrise this curve as $(x,y)=r(\theta)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos\theta+\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin\theta+\frac{1}{2}\right)$ for $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$. A quick check shows that $|r'(\theta)|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. So then the integral is
$$\int_Cf(x,y)ds = \int_0^{2\pi}f(r(\theta))|r'(\theta)|d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi}\left(\frac{1}{2}(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)d\theta,$$
which I'm sure you can work out.

3: A genuine double integral over the disc $D:x^2+y^2\leq x+y$. We can parametrise this in (I believe) a clearer way than has already been given: $(x,y)=\left(r\cos\theta+\frac{1}{2},r\sin\theta+\frac{1}{2}\right)$, for $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ and $r\in[0,1/\sqrt{2}]$. Recall that the area element in polar coordinates is $dxdy=rdrd\theta$. Thus the integral is:
$$\iint_D(x+y)dxdy=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{1/\sqrt{2}}\left(r^2(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)+r\right)drd\theta.$$
This splits into two terms and each term is simply the product of 2 1-variable integrals, so I'm sure you can work this out as well.

Comment: I believe that the OP was asking how to evaluate the double integral on the disk without making a translational transformation.  ;-)

Comment: That was by no means clear from what they said.

Comment: The OP wrote "But i don't understand how to find polar radius change interval here.  If I separate circle into two, for first half circle for example it will go from some point to $π/2$. I don't understand how to find that some point, cause it starts from point $(1/2−1/√2=−0.2071)," referring to the picture that immediately precedes the statement.  It was quite clear to me and to @zkutch.  Of course, this does not mean it is clear to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that we integrate on $x^2+y^2\leqslant x+y$, as noted by @Tom Sharpe, we can obtain all necessary limits from $0 \leqslant r = \sin \phi + \cos \phi$

For example, let's obtain limits for $\phi$:

we have $\sin \phi + \cos \phi = \sqrt{2} \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4} - \phi \right)$. Now most simple is draw graphic of this function and see where is it positive - we will see $[-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4}] $ as one possible solution, which agrees with geometrical view from $Oxy$ plane, that circle is in one side of $y=-x$ line. Obviously any other solution, from periodic nature of trigonometric function, is acceptable. Another way is take formal definition of $\cos$ and find mentioned segment from it. Result will be same.
$$\int\limits_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}\int\limits_{0}^{\sin \phi + \cos \phi}r^2(\sin \phi + \cos \phi)d \phi dr$$
I would like to say that the path indicated by  @Alexey Burdin is closer to my heart, although, the decisive factor here, may be, is question what better to optimize - the limits of the integral or the integrand.

Comment: @ Mark Viola. Sorry, but same I can ask you. When I hit finish, then fabulously appeared your answer. I've been writing this answer for over ten minutes and when I started here was nothing.

Comment: Yes.  The time stamp has mine posted one or two minutes before yours.  But no worry.  You hadn't seen mine, so all is OK.

Comment: @ Mark Viola. Thanks for understanding. You see I often leave working and not completed way in chat for some time and I feel both surprise and awkwardness and I just feel uncomfortable, when someone has already written that I was working on. The question arises: I do not see the answers of others until they are published, but is it possible for someone to see what and how I am editing?

Comment: thanks, and how did you get $\frac{3\pi}{4} and \frac{-\pi}{4}$

Comment: @ manabou11. Added to answer. Feel free to ask anything you'll find interesting.

Comment: thanks, this part $\sin \phi + \cos \phi = \sqrt{2} \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4} - \phi \right)$ is really not clear to me. Is it a formula? We got that $\sin \phi + \cos \phi = r$, but why its $\sqrt{2} \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4} - \phi \right)$?

Comment: Yes, it is formula. Most easy way to obtain it use to right part formula for $\cos(\alpha - \beta)$ and you are done.